# L317T voltage regulator output too low

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, output

I got a L317T voltage regulator. I connected it to a 12V input, but the output which i get is only ~0,32Volts instead of ~5Volts. Why is that happening. Its not a problematic regulator. Every one of them did the same thing. With or without the capacitors, the regulator gave me a very low voltage
[image]

Comment: Sounds like bad design or fake parts. Either way, you'd need to post a schematic of what you did showing your load and all components.

Comment: That cannot be answered until you post which external resistors and capacitors you used, and how you connected them.

Comment: @Andyaka Its a very basic design. There is just a wire connected to the input, a ground wire connected to the input and an output wire. I did not use any external resistors or capacitors. Just the regulator

Comment: There's the error. You need external resistors, otherwise the LM317 will not know what its output voltage is.

Comment: where i should put the external resistor? How many ohms?

Comment: Your schematic is from a 7805. This is completely different to a LM317. Read [the LM317 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) (chapter 9) to see how to set the output voltage.

Comment: @StarCat ohhh thank you very much. I thought all kinds of regulators worked the same way

Comment: OK, bad design then. Not all biscuits are chocolate although I wish they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit is for 7805 regulator. An 317 won't work in a circuit meant for 7805.

In addition, regulators need input and output capacitors, they won't work stably if you leave them out on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The three terminals of the LM317 are \$V_{in}\$, \$V_{out}\$, and \$Adjust\$.  The terminals of the 7805 are \$V_{in}\$, \$V_{out}\$, and \$Gnd\$. The \$Adjust\$ pin of the LM317 should be biased. But the ground pin of the 7805 should be grounded. (Also, as mentioned in comment below, the pinouts of the two devices are not compatible.)

Comment: Good to mention the pin difference, but also the pinout is not compatible in any way. So on contrary to what you said, adjust is not grounded. 7805 has in/gnd/out, while 317 has adj/out/in so in that circuit 12V has been applied to adjust pin while out is connected to ground.

Comment: D'oh. You are right. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

LM317 is adjustable regulator. Voltage divider,two resistor is must. It keeps 1.25 volts between VOUT and ADJ pin.

Comment: It does not keep 1.25V on adj pin. It keeps 1.25V between Vout and adj pins. There is a big difference.

Comment: @Justme. Thank you